# Read the fields of the container of a collection

Tags: collections, lektor

I have a container for example: students.{title, description, children=student} and student={title, ...}

```
# students.ini
[model]
name = Students

[fields.title]
label = Title
type = string

[fields.description]
label = Description
type = markdown

[children]
model = student
```

```
# student.ini
[model]
name = Student

[fields.title]
label = Title
type = string
```

I would like to get the title/description of the studentS container.

```
{% set root = site.get('/students') %}
{{ root.description }}
```

But with `get` or `query`, I get the list and not the container...

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you have to access the `record` attribute first:

```
{{ site.get('/students').record.description }}
```

... and you can always access the `.parent` attribute of a child.